# Components dependency check

Tags: api, versioning, dependency-management, docker

Lets say you have 2 docker stacks: `stack-A.yml` defines **serviceA** and `stack-B.yml` defines **serviceB**; you also have an **archive** of common data that will be mounted by services.

How could I verify that APIs exposed by a given version of **serviceA** is compliant with what a given version of **serviceB** needs?

How could I verify that the version of the services is compatible with the version of the common data **archive**?

Is there any tool that does this dependency check?
I would prefer the verification to be static and not at runtime when I deploy the stack.

I haven't found anything useful searching for "dependency management": I only found information on npm, maven, apt, etc., but I don'y think I can use them for my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You need unit and/or integration tests for the APIs exposed by your services to make sure they are complaint.

Comment: For what I learnt unit tests should not use other services but their mocks and integration tests are not related to which versions are compliant (just to compliance between services).